# How to calculate the SHA1 in iphone

Tags: iphone, sha1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a library for iPhone to work with HMAC-SHA-1 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476455/is-there-a-library-for-iphone-to-work-with-hmac-sha-1-encoding)
>   [Trying to Write NSString sha1 function, but it’s returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353771/trying-to-write-nsstring-sha1-function-but-its-returning-null)
>   [Objective C: SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468268/objective-c-sha1)

How to calculate the SHA1 of NSString in iphone?Which api can be used ?

Comment: Perhaps you can use one of the suggestions posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353771/trying-to-write-nsstring-sha1-function-but-its-returning-null

Comment: You should really have googled before asking - there is a ton of links available - it all boils down to using <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476455/is-there-a-library-for-iphone-to-work-with-hmac-sha-1-encoding) will help you