# Check duplicate value of UIImage in sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimage

My application contains images in SQLite database. I want to check for duplicate values of UIImage before I insert it in to the database. The image is stored as blob type. Is this possible?

Comment: you can check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm.  Also you can convert your blob data to NSData and then you can compare two NSData object.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to store a hash, like [sha1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468268/objective-c-sha1), of the image data in another field of the database then compare against that.

Comment: +1 specifically, this would *significantly* reduce the number of images which must be compared and make the operation very fast over large collections (databases) *although* the images with matching hashes would still need to be compared.

Comment: That link for sha1 shows how to get a hash from `NSData`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3469033/239380

Comment: Iam doing like this way. NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image);  
        NSLog(@"imgdata=%@",imgData);
        UIImage *dataImage=[[UIImage alloc] init];
        dataImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        NSLog(@"image new=%@",dataImage);
         NSString  *sqlTmp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Images where imgName= '%@'",dataImage];
        const char *sqlstmt=[sqlTmp UTF8String];