# Is there any Two-Legged OAuth library support RSA-SHA1 signing for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth

I was trying to implement MasterCard MoneySend API in iOS. The API require two-legged oauth to authorize the request.

The criteria are:

1. OAuth should use `RSA-SHA1` for generating signature.
2. request method should be `PUT`
3. since the request has a body, need to include body hash.

What we have is a ConsumerKey and .p12 file of PrivetKey. I tryed many libraries like `RestKit`, `ASIHTTPRequest`, `OAuthConsumer`, etc.

Finally I ended up with this piece of code:

```
#import "NSStringAdditions.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "sha.h"
#import "rsa.h"
#import "pem.h"
#import "objects.h"

#define SANDBOX_CONSUMER_KEY @""
#define PRIVETKEY @""

@interface MC_TestApi ()
<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection;
}
@end

@implementation MC_TestApi

- (NSString*)oAuthBodyHash:(NSData*)body
{
    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    SHA1([body bytes], [body length], (unsigned char*)&digest);

    unsigned c = SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;
    uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        int byte = (unsigned int)digest[i];
        bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;
    }
    NSData *strData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:c freeWhenDone:YES];

    return [NSString base64StringFromData:strData length:strData.length ];
}

- (NSString *)sha1RsaText: (NSString *)text
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"MCOpenAPI" ofType: @"pem"];
    FILE *secretFile = fopen([path cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding], "r");
    if (secretFile==NULL){
        printf("ERROR opening RSA Keys failed test.pem\n");
        return nil;
    }


    NSData *clearTextData = [text dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char encryptedData[40];
    RSA *rsa = (RSA *)PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(secretFile, &rsa, NULL, NULL);

    unsigned int encryptionLength = 40; //RSA_size(rsa);

    RSA_sign(NID_sha1, [clearTextData bytes], [clearTextData length], encryptedData, &encryptionLength, rsa);

    unsigned c = 20;
    uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        int byte = (unsigned int)encryptedData[i];
        bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;
    }
    NSData *strData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:c freeWhenDone:YES];

    return [NSString base64StringFromData:strData length:strData.length ];
}

- (NSString *)urlEncodeValue:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *) CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                              (CFStringRef)str,
                                                                                              NULL,
                                                                                              CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;="),
                                                                                              kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return result;
}

-(void)requestWithOAuth {

    NSUInteger time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

    NSString *timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", time];
    NSString *urlString = @"https://sandbox.api.mastercard.com/moneysend/eligibility/v1/pan";
    NSString *nonce = @"1234567890";
    NSString *consumerKey = SANDBOX_CONSUMER_KEY;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?Format=XML",urlString]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSString *bodyString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?> <PanEligibilityRequest> <SendingAccountNumber>5555555555559999</SendingAccountNumber> </PanEligibilityRequest>";

    NSData *body = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *bodyLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[body length]];
    [request setValue:bodyLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-length"];

    NSString *oAuthBodyHash = [self oAuthBodyHash:body];

    NSString *header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"oauth_timestamp=\"%@\",oauth_nonce=\"%@\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_body_hash=\"%@\",oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\",oauth_signature_method=\"RSA-SHA1\"",timestamp,nonce,oAuthBodyHash,SANDBOX_CONSUMER_KEY];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       consumerKey,@"oauth_consumer_key",
                                       nonce,@"oauth_nonce",
                                       @"RSA-SHA1",@"oauth_signature_method",
                                       timestamp,@"oauth_timestamp",
                                       @"1.0",@"oauth_version",
                                       oAuthBodyHash,@"oauth_body_hash",
                                       @"XML",@"Format",
                                       nil];
    NSArray *keys = [parameters allKeys];

    NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
    keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    NSString *test = @"";
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i<[keys count]; i++) {
        NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",key,[parameters objectForKey:key]];
        if (i!=([parameters count]-1))
            str = [str stringByAppendingString:@","];
        test = [test stringByAppendingString:str];
    }

    NSString *signatureString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"PUT&%@%%26%@",
                                 [self urlEncodeValue: urlString],
                                 [self urlEncodeValue: [test stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"," withString: @"&"]]];

    NSString *signature = [self sha1RsaText: signatureString];
    NSString *finalAuthHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"OAuth %@,oauth_signature=\"%@\"", header, signature];
    [request setValue:finalAuthHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [urlConnection start];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnectionDelegate

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"in didReceiveResponse %i %@",code,[NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:code]);

    responseData = nil;
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"in didReceiveData ");
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSLog(@"\n\n ERORR \n\n%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (responseData) {
        NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
        NSLog(@"XML: %@",newStr);

    }
    responseData = nil;
}

@end
```

**My question is:**

- What I am doing wrong here?
- Is there any Open source library in iOS that i can use?

Guys Please help me on this... thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [chilkatsoft](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/rsa-objc.asp) 
or just native [CommonCrypto (an Apple framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469033/887325)

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually i am looking for a two-legged oauth open source library. Using `openssl` I can do what these two framework capable of. And this `chilkatsoft` is paid service :(

Comment: >chilkatsoft is paid service
Yea its true. GitHub is better way. but you need spend a lot of time to find the best solve. And if you not have time for search, just buy chilkatsoft ^_^. 
P.S. Maybe Base64 library work incorrect. Use validated library https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

Comment: Base64 is working fine i checked input and output with online tools. I believe that there some logical error in OAuth implemented `-(void)requestWithOAuth` method, thats why i am looking for two-legged OAuth library.

Comment: I need more time for understand your mistake.