# SHA1 hash producing different result in Objective-C and C#.NET

Tags: .net, ios, objective-c, hash, sha1

Basically I want to write function that computes sha1 hash.

So far I have tried is as follows.

**C#.NET**

```
byte[] p2 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("password");
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] result = sha.ComputeHash(p2);
string encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
```

*Output :* 6Pl/upEE0epQR5SObftn+s2fW3M=

**Objective-C**

I have added classes for Base64 from [NSData_Base64 Classes reference](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip).

```
NSString *password = @"password";
NSData *data = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *unicodePassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
data = [unicodePassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];


unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hash);
NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSLog(@"Result: %@",[result base64EncodedString]);
```

*Output :* dYusXVhObIBzJMgg1E1FJ9cK1NY=

Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Why these two values differs ?

Please correct my mistakes.

Comment: maybe "NSData_Base64 Classes reference" works with URL safe base64, but C#.NET's System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 works with URL-unsafe one? Try using online SHA1 encryptors/decryptors to compare results. I am suggesting to use GData Base64 that can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong, since you interpret UTF8 encoded data as if it was Unicode encoded:

`NSString *unicodePassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];`

Replce the second line with:
`NSData *data = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];`

The 2 first bytes in data is a BOM (Byte order mark).

Remove these 2 bytes with
`data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[data bytes] + 2 length:[data length] - 2];`

...and then hash that data any you will have the same hash as in C#.

Comment: I tried but not working output is RsVAbAblCcyoeiKAeH+6zWWZ6Ok= now.

Comment: Edited the post on how to remove the BOM.

Comment: Wow!!! thanks this is working. Can you please elaborate what is "Byte order mark" and how to detect and resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

For further information I found that SHA1 function can have some results..

So I have implemented methods at this link: [MD5 and SHA1 iOS implementation](http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/how-to-get-md5-and-sha1-in-objective-c-ios-sdk/) linked by [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483246/sha1-for-specific-string-in-ios)

and I refine it with my integration that send as parameters if you send UTF8-encoding string or not (unicode one) and if you want hexadecimal string or decimal one

```
- (NSString*) sha1UTF8Encoding:(BOOL)utf8 andDecimal:(BOOL)decimal
{
    const char *cstr;
    if (utf8) {
        cstr = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }else{
        cstr = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    }
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:self.length];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
        if (decimal) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%i", digest[i]];
        }else{
            [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
        }
    }

    return output;    
}
```

(Note that I implemented this method in a NSString Category)

With this I tested that you can use it for many purpose sha1 operation, for example with this configuration:

```
NSString* sha1 = [stringToTest sha1UTF8Encoding:YES andDecimal:YES];
```

sha1 variable match with the one product by the C# method found at this link: [Hashing using the SHA1 class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38951/How-To-Hash-Data-Using-MD5-and-SHA1)